# bash script for formatting file in specific output

Tags: bash, shell

I have input file in following format. I need to help in arrange the file in following format.
INput FIle

```
    Symmetrix ID                : 00000000000
Storage Group Name          : RSVD_BAUPATCHING_8458588_88GB-T2_10-03-17
Last update time            : 12:10:37 PM on Thu Mar 09,2017
   Devices                  : 0370F:03716 
Symmetrix ID                : 00000000000
Storage Group Name          : RSVD_BTO_WO6809798_3TB-T1_05-05-16
Last update time            : 09:05:13 PM on Tue Aug 02,2016
   Devices                  : 03C6A:03C72 
Symmetrix ID                : 00000000000
Storage Group Name          : RSVD_DIABETIC_7924216_640GB-T2_29-11-16
Last update time            : 01:55:52 AM on Tue Nov 29,2016
   Devices                  : 035A7:035B0 
Symmetrix ID                : 00000000000
Storage Group Name          : RSVD_DR_WO6694561_90TB-T3_R6_19-04-16
Last update time            : 05:18:32 PM on Wed May 11,2016
   Devices                  : 03C7B 03C7D 050B4 050C4 050D4 050E4 050F4 
                              050FC 05114 0511C 05124 0512C 05134 0513C 
                              05144 0514C 05154 0515C 05164 0516C 05354 
                              05364 05374 05384 05394 053A4 053B4 053C4 
                              053D4 053E4 053F4 05404 05414 05424 05434 
                              05444 05454 05464 05474 05484 05494 054A4 
                              054B4 054C4 054D4 055C4 055D4 055E4 055F4 
                              05604 05614 05624 056A4 056B4 056C4 056D4 
                              056E4 056F4 05704 05804 05814 05824 05834 
                              05844 05854 05864 058F4 
Symmetrix ID                : 00000000000
Storage Group Name          : RSVD_DR_WO6694561_90TB-T3_R6_19-04-16
Last update time            : 04:28:03 PM on Wed May 11,2016
   Devices                  : 033DE 033E4:033E5 033E9:033EB 033F2:033F3 
                              033F6 033F8 033FC 03400 03404 03408 0341C:0341D 
                              03967:03968 0396B:0396F 03976:03978 0397E 
                              03980:03982 03986:03988 0398C 0398E:03991 
                              03996 03998:03999 0399C:0399D 039A0:039A4 
                              039AA 039AC:039AD 039B0:039B1 039B4 039B6:039B7 
                              039BA 039BC:039BE 039C2 03A82 03A84 03A86:03A88 
                              03A8C:03A8D 03A90:03A92 03A96 03A98:03AA0 
                              03AAA 03AAC 03AAE 03AB0 03AB2 03AB4 03AB6:03AB8 
                              03ABC:03AC3 03ACC:03AD0 03AD6 03AD8:03ADD 
                              03AE4:03AE5 03AE8:03AE9 03AEC:03AEE 03B7D 
                              03B83 03B87 03B8D 03B8F 03B91 03B93 03B95 
                              03B97 03B99 03B9B 03BAF 03BB3 03BB7 03BBB
```

I want output in following format

```
RSVD_DR_WO6694561_90TB-T3_R6_19-04-16,May 11,2016,03C7B 03C7D 050B4 050C4 050D4 050E4 050F4 050FC 05114 0511C 05124 0512C 05134 0513C 05144 0514C 05154 0515C 05164 0516C 05354 05364 05374 05384 05394 053A4 053B4 053C4 053D4 053E4 053F4 05404 05414 05424 05434 05444 05454 05464 05474 05484 05494 054A4 054B4 054C4 054D4 055C4 055D4 055E4 055F4 05604 05614 05624 056A4 056B4 056C4 056D4 056E4 056F4 05704 05804 05814 05824 05834 05844 05854 05864 058F4

RSVD_DR_WO6694561_90TB-T3_R6_19-04-16,May 11,2016,033DE 033E4:033E5 033E9:033EB 033F2:033F3 033F6 033F8 033FC 03400 03404 03408 0341C:0341D 03967:03968 0396B:0396F 03976:03978 0397E 03980:03982 03986:03988 0398C 0398E:03991 03996 03998:03999 0399C:0399D 039A0:039A4 039AA 039AC:039AD 039B0:039B1 039B4 039B6:039B7 039BA 039BC:039BE 039C2 03A82 03A84 03A86:03A88 03A8C:03A8D 03A90:03A92 03A96 03A98:03AA0 3AAA 03AAC 03AAE 03AB0 03AB2 03AB4 03AB6:03AB8 03ABC:03AC3 03ACC:03AD0 03AD6 03AD8:03ADD 03AE4:03AE5 03AE8:03AE9 03AEC:03AEE 03B7D 03B83 03B87 03B8D 03B8F 03B91 03B93 03B95 03B97 03B99 03B9B 03BAF 03BB3 03BB7 03BBB
```

I need RSVD at the starting of the line. comma separated after that I want the last date and next are all the values for the RSVD.

I able to get RSVD and the last date but I am not able to get all the values next to them comma separated. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ...so, to be clear, the only thing you're having trouble with is changing spaces to commas?

Comment: `s=${s// /,}` will give you a version of your string `"$s"` with all spaces changed to commas -- easy.

Comment: Or, if you've formed contents into an array, you can set `IFS=,` and then emit `"${array[*]}"` to get a comma-delimited form.

Comment: It might be helpful to show your existing work, so we can better identify exactly what extension it still needs.